# Some doubts related to the C# CultureInfo and the relation with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, globalization, cultureinfo

I am pretty new in C# and I have the following doubt about how work the **System.Globalization.CultureInfo** class.

I have the following situation.

In a class I read some value (from an XML using XPath) that contains some informations as some data field.

So I have something like it:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureEN = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");

currentDeepSightVuln.LastUpdated = DateTime.Parse(n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:LastUpdated", nsmgr).InnerText, cultureEN);
```

In my XML file this field is:

```
<x:LastUpdated>2014-05-21T17:00:38</x:LastUpdated>
```

So it value is **2014-05-21T17:00:38**

Running my program when it is performed the previous operation (that initialize the **LastUpdate object property) I have that the **LastUpdate** property value is: **{21/05/2014 17:00:38}**.

As you can see it have another format than the XML field value. I think that this is pretty normal because it is converted basing it on the **en-GB** settings.

My doubt is: if then I save my object on a database table (Microsoft SQL Server) can I have some problem or it is reconverted in the corrected form from SQL Server?

**EDIT 1:**
To insert my object into db I use something like it:

public long insert(DataModel.Vulnerability.Vuln v)
        {

```
        _strSQL = "";
        string strSQLParametri = "";
        string query = "";

        long newId;
        long VulnerabilityAlertDocumentPkValue;

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        try
        {
            _transactionBegin();
            // [VulnerabilityAlertId] insertion on the DB:
            if (v.VulnerabilityAlertId != null)
            {
                _strSQL = "INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument ( [VulnerabilityAlertId] ";
                strSQLParametri = " VALUES (@VULNERABILITYALERTID ";
                _addParameter(command, "@VULNERABILITYALERTID ", newId);
            }

            ........................................................................
            ........................................................................
            ........................................................................

            _strSQL += ",[PUBLISHED] ";
            strSQLParametri += ", @PUBLISHED ";
            _addParameter(command, "@PUBLISHED", v.Published);

            ........................................................................
            ........................................................................
            ........................................................................

            query = _strSQL + " ) " + strSQLParametri + " );";
            command.CommandText = query;
            _executeNoQuery(command);

            VulnerabilityAlertDocumentPkValue = _getIdentity();
            Debug.WriteLine("PK della tabella VulnerabilityAlertDocumentPkValue: " + VulnerabilityAlertDocumentPkValue);
```

Tnx

Comment: how do you save to database from application (SqlCommand)? and what datatype for the column of the database (datetime, varchar)?

Comment: The value of datetime is something of int type, and it doesn't matter how you are vewing it. So saving it by type datetime will not change the value regarding culture properties. It will be reconverted.

Comment: @rudym not quite an int; the *days* are the integer part; the *time* is the decimal part

Comment: @YuliamChandra Yes I use command, I have edited my original post adding some information about how I perform the query at the end of my original post

Comment: With the edit, I'm confused why the question talks about xml - nothing in the edit demonstrates xml. As a side note: if you *must* build the TSQL gradually (rather than all at once), you might want to consider `StringBuilder` - there's a lot of intermediate `string`s involved there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't actually about culture, isn't about en-GB, and isn't about SQL server; more simply, xml defines dates as specified in ISO 8601 format. That's the end of it.

You ***should not use*** `DateTime.Parse` specifying `en-GB` with xml. That is **incorrect**.

A correct implementation would be:

```
DateTime when = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(...);
```

Or more conveniently, if using `XElement` etc:

```
DateTime when = (DateTime)el;
```

If you want to talk about dates in SQL server *away* from xml, then simply: treat them as `date` or `datetime` (rather than strings) - either via typed columns or as typed parameters. Then there is never any confusion over format or locale.

---

With your edit, again this is unrelated to xml. Assuming that `v.Published` is a `DateTime`, and `[PUBLISHED]` is a `datetime`, then it should work fine - these values **are never strings**. A `DateTime` / `datetime` is actually a *number* (some defined interval into a defined epoch). And since they are never strings, again: culture and format *does not become involved*.

Comment: MMM so are you saying me that if I put a date (take from my XML) into a DateTime field and then I put it into the DB I will have no problem?

Comment: ok...and what it will appean if instead a correct date (as <x:LastUpdated>2014-05-21T17:00:38</x:LastUpdated>) I will have an incorrect date as <x:LastUpdated>2014-20-10T17:00:38</x:LastUpdated> ???

Comment: @AndreaNobili as long as you take it from the xml **correctly**, then indeed: there should be no issues. If you have an incorrect date such as `2014-20-10T...` then `XmlConvert` should refuse to parse it.

Comment: Ok, I tryed and if the date is incorrect it explod throwing an exception

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're confused how to read or write datetime data from / to database.

if you have datetime column in database

```
create table anything
(
    published datetime
)
```

when you save it to database you need to save it as datetime object or valid datetime string, because there is automatic conversion if you pass the parameter as string.

```
// Writes.
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog=master; Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("insert into anything (published) values (@published)", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@published", "2014-05-21T17:00:38");
    // Not working as it will throw "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@published", "2014-12345-21T17:00:38");
    command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

but when you read it from database it will automatically become datetime object.

```
// Reads.
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog=master; Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("select * from anything", connection);
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var publishedDate = (DateTime)reader["published"];
    }
}
```